# Netty:why use volatile field defaultFactory in InternalLoggerFactory of netty source code?

Tags: singleton, netty, volatile

When I read source code of netty,I am confused.

- Threre is a **volatile** field  **defaultFactory** in class InternalLoggerFactory,In my opinion,if to implement the singleton,why method of "**getDefaultFactory**" do not have a **synchronized** keyword or double check，Only keyword of **volatile** are used here

Comment: Where in the source code are you referring?

Comment: source code of netty 4.1, and "common" module.

Answer (score 0):

This is because volatile gives good enough protection here while very cheap (especially on x86).

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you please explain for me why does it give a good enough protection  only use volatile,
in my opinion，the only use of "InternalLoggerFactory"  is Class initialization,so invoke  of method  "getDefaultFactory"  only in Class initialization,And  Class initialization has a lock,is that reason?